# find variable from polynomial when divisor and remainder is known

Tags: polynomials

I am asked the following question:

When ${x^4 - 3x^3 + px - 5}$ is divided by ${x - 3}$ the remainder is $16$, find $p$.

So my way of solving this was to use synthetic long division to divide ${x^4 - 3x^3 + px - 5}$ by $3$ that would leave me with a remainder expression that would have $p$.
$$
\begin{matrix}3&1&0&-3&p&-5\\
&&3&9&18&54+3p\\
&1&3&6&18+p&49+3p
\end{matrix}
%3| 1 |  0 | -3  |  p      |  -5
% |      3 |  9  |  18     |  54 + 3p
%   
%  | 1 | 3 |  6  |  18 + p |  49 + 3p
$$

I get the remainder to be ${3p + 49}$

I would say then that ${3p + 49 = 16}$ and ${p = - 11}

But the textbook gives an answer of $7$.

Have I come to the wrong conclusion about how to work out ${p}$?

Comment: The remainder should be $3p-5$ as the first two terms is a multiple of $x-3$. You must have made some mistakes in your long division. Unfortunately it is not in a human readable format so I can't say where exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,

The polynomial $x^4-3x^3+px-5-16$ i.e. $x^4-3x^3+px-21$ is completely divisible by $(x-3)$

hence, $(x-3)$ is a factor of $x^4-3x^3+px-21$

Hence, $x=3$ will satisfy the polynomial $x^4-3x^3+px-21$ as follows 
$$(3)^4-3(3)^3+p(3)-21=0$$  $$3p=21\implies \color{red}{p=7}$$

Comment: why is it - 16 and not 16 for the remainder that is added onto the polynomial?

Comment: OK, the remainder is always non-negative.

Comment: If I understand the remainder theorem correctly, it states:

${f(x) = (x-c)·q(x) + r}$ 

But in the answers here you are subtracting 16 rather than adding 16.  I don't understand why

Comment: Notice, remainder is non-negative which is always subtracted from a given  number for complete divisibility. It should not be added to the number as it  will not make the number completely divisible

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $f(x)=(x-3)\cdot g(x)+r(x)$ implies $f(3)=r(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that $(x-3)|(x^4-3x^3+px-5-[16])$ or, 
$$(x-3)|(x^4-3x^3+px-21)$$

Now say that $$x^4-3x^3+px-21=(x-3)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$$ $$=ax^4+(b-3a)x^3+(c-3b)x^2+(d-3c)x-3d$$

So you get that easily comparing LHS and RHS that $$d=7,a=1,b=0,c=0$$ Hence $$p=d-3c=7$$

Comment: Though your answer is right, you seem to have complicated things unnecessariy. Working with p(3) = 16 would have solved it instantaneously. I will not downvote it, since yours is also an approach to follow, and let this answer be very much here.

Answer (score -1):

Let $$P(x)= x^4-3x^3+px-5, \quad g(x)=x-3,$$
  so,
$$
\begin{align}
      P(3)&= 3^4-(3)(3)^3+p(3)-5\\
      P(3)&= 81-81+3p-5\\
      P(3)&= 3p-5.
\end{align}
$$
Note that the remainder is $16$.
Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
     P(3) &= 16\\
     3p-5 &= 16\\
     3p/3 &= 21/3.
\end{align}
$$
So,     $$p = 7.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.